# RMAN ERROR: BACKUP command not found

Tags: oracle-19c

I have an Oracle database 19c with IP, *x.x.x.a* that have a lot of important tables. I want to get backup of that and save it on another system with IP,*x.x.x.b*. I did this actions on the *x.x.x.b* system:

- Install an Oracle database 19c which won't be used to have data in his own.
- Install Oracle database client 19c and set ORACLE_HOME in **~/.bashrc**
- Set JAVA_HOME
- Finally, use this script to get backup of the Oracle Database on *x.x.x.a*:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/oracle_database_client
  export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
  rman target sys/******@//x.x.x.a:1521/ORCL

  BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0 DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG FORMAT '/home/oracle/backup_oracle_process/backup_files/%U';
  exit;
  ```

I prefer to get backup using script in the clear way and use the script in *crontab* to run every week.
I gave **+x** permission to the script,*backup_script.sh*, and  run it. But unfortunately, it stop on **RMAN>** prompt and when exited from that this error message was shown:

> BACKUP command not found.

Would you please guide me how to solve the problem and have a script to get backup of Oracle database?

Any help is really appreciated.